# Finding a the "sub-path" in a hierarchical system, Java

Tags: java, recursion

I have this Hierarchical file system that is built like so:

```
class StorageUnit{
    String name;
    StorageUnit(String nameInput){
        this.name = nameInput;
    }
}

class Folder extends StorageUnit{
    ArrayList<StorageUnit> items = new ArrayList<StorageUnit>();
    
    void addContent(StorageUnit item){
         this.items.add(item);
    }
}

class File extends StorageUnit{}
```

Given a path (not necessarily the complete path) for example for this system:

```
A
|    B
|    |    C
|    |    |    code.java
|    |    bye.log
|    Aa.txt
|    aa.py
```

a path be given like so:

```
B/C/code.java
```

I am trying to make a function return the specified **File** if there exists a path where the given path is part of it, for example if it finds the path:

```
A/B/C/code.java
```

the function would return `code.java` since the found path contains the given path,
**else** it returns null.

I thought about recursion, however, can't figure out what to do it if I end up in a file that doesn't contain the file am looking for:

```
//The entire code here belongs to the class StorageUnit

public File findFile(String path){
        String[] paths = path.split("/");

        return findFile_aux(paths,0);
    }
public File findFile_aux(String[] paths, int i){
        for(StorageItem item : this.items){
            if(item.getName().equals(paths[i])){
                if(i == paths.length-1) {
                    return ((File) item);
                }
                item.findFile_aux(paths, i+1);
            }
            item.findFile_aux(paths, i);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You missed to return your recursive call
2. You have to give the current folder to the recursive call, otherwise you allways look at `A`'s items.
3. You get a `ClassCastException` if your path leads to a folder

```
private static File find(Folder root, String path) {
    return find(path.split("/"), Collections.singletonList(root), 0);
}

private static File find(String[] path, List<StorageUnit> units, int depth) {
    if (depth >= path.length) {
        // file not found
        return null;
    }
    String currentStep = path[depth];
    for (StorageUnit unit : units) {
        if (currentStep.equals(unit.name)) {
            // step found
            if (depth == path.length - 1) {
                // last step -> unit found
                if (unit instanceof File) {
                    return (File) unit;
                } else {
                    // path doesn't lead to a file (point 3)
                    System.err.println("path doesn't leed to a file but " + unit);
                    return null;
                }
            } else if (unit instanceof Folder) {
                // next step
                Folder folder = (Folder) unit;
                // recursive call with items of current folder (point 2)
                File file = find(path, folder.items, depth + 1);
                if (file != null) {
                    // found it (point 1)
                    return file;
                }
                // else -> not found -> ignore unit
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Suppose we have this System
https://pastebin.com/CYhSGYWG
How does the code "go back" for example if we end up in the DETER folder?

Comment: What do you mean with "go back"?
If you also want to return folders you just have to change the return type to `StorageUnit` and remove `instanceof` to return the `unit` directly.

Answer (score 0):

It is not nessesary to use recursion, you can use SimpleFileVisitor:

```
public class FileFounder {

    private Path path;
    private List<String> fileList = new ArrayList<>();

    public FileFounder(Path path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public List<String> getStringPathList() throws IOException {
        Files.walkFileTree(path, new SFV());
        return fileList;
    }

    private class SFV extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path> {

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path path, BasicFileAttributes attrs) {
            fileList.add(path.toAbsolutePath().toString());
            return CONTINUE;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
FileFounder fileFounder = new FileFounder(rootPath);
List<String> listOfStringAdressOfFilesInRoot = fileFounder.getStringPathList();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, can't use external libraries

Comment: SimpleFileVisitor - it is path of java 8, package java.nio.file